# Before reading "A Grain of Wheat," what historical facts and cultural context are useful to know?

Tags: historical-context, a-grain-of-wheat, ngugi-wa-thiongo, cultural-context

I'm looking to read *A Grain of Wheat*, by Ngũgĩ wa Thiong'o. However, I'm very unfamiliar with the history and culture of Kenya, to the point where I know practically nothing about it.

But I do know this: that the history of Kenya is long and complicated, and the culture of Kenya is, well, a *culture*. Absorbing it *all* before reading this book seems a little unnecessary, bordering on impossible.

My question, then, is: what should I already know (or familiarize myself with) before going into this book? Do I need geopolitical context? What key elements of Kenyan culture and history should I read about before I pick up this book?

Comment: I can't comment on Kenyan culture, but "A Grain of Wheat" instantly made me think of the Pablo Neruda poem "El monte y el rio" ("The mountain and the river"). I mention it because the book you're asking about seems to deal with social issues, and Neruda was writing about the suffering of the common people--the redness of the wheat in Neruda has socialist implications.